# redis client list retruns "cmd=NULL"

Tags: redis

When I do `client list` on redis-cli, I found some events showing `cmd=NULL`.

eg:

```
id=198375 addr=10.213.96.168:37090 fd=696 name= age=8064 idle=8064 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=NULL
```

What are those `cmd=NULL` events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmd=xxx` shows the `LAST COMMAND` that the client executed.

However, if the client connects to Redis, and has NOT executed any command, then there's no `LAST COMMAND`, and its last command is `NULL`.